# change word in referred url to direct to correct page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I recently changed a word in my query string in my url, which causes the query to break, so I wish to redirect the old url to the new one.  example:

```
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Windermere&result=2
```

new url

```
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/?q=Windermere&page=2
```

What would be the best solution for this, is there anyway do it in php or is it a htaccess rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your page, you can simply use this hotfix:

```
if(isset($_GET['result']))$_GET['page']=$_GET['result'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['result']))$_REQUEST['page']=$_REQUEST['result'];
```

Comment: This works great thanks, but I am thinking this would cause duplicate pages?

Comment: In that case, htaccess with a 301 would be more suitable.